# Split by regex with no particular range

Tags: java, regex

im facing a problem regarding parsing of this text. I want to split it by unique account#. see below:

```
Account#: 1
    Data1
    Data2
    Data3
Account#: 1
    Data4
    Data5
    Data6
Account#: 1
    Data7
    Data8
    Data9
Account#: 2
    Data10
    Data11
    Data12
Account#: 2
    Data13
    Data14
    Data15
Account#: 3
    Data16
    Data17
    Data18
Account#: 3
    Data19
    Data20
    Data21
```

The result should be in my first index it will composed of Account#: 1 with Data1-9, then in my second index Account#: 2 with Data 10-15 and so on.. ("Data" here is composed of new lines and etc)

I'm thinking to use the split(regex) but, how can i regex the range of account#? is there any chance that regex can match unique values?

Thanks for the response.

Comment: Why do you want to do this with regular expressions in particular? I don't think they are a good tool for this task.

Comment: Why cant you use a Map?

Comment: Because this file is so big that if I will manually check it by reading the lines, it will take time. I have also my idea to parse it but I want to seek other options that will use the split function.

Comment: I would use a `BufferedReader` and the `readLine()` method. You can do sth like that: `if(line.contains('#') && line.charAt(line.length()-1)!=currentAccountNo){ //change account number}`

Answer (score 1):

Using a regular expression will still require the file to be read / scanned. A reg exp is simply a way of efficiently scanning the data, once read from the file.

Why not implement something simple to read the file once, line-by-line. As you are reading it and encounter each Account #, write the data that follows to a unique file for that account #, or alternatively to an in-memory data structure, such as a java.util.Map keyed by the Account # (if the data will fit in-memory).

If you write this efficiently, with data going to an output file per account #, you will only need to read the input file once (which a regular expression approach would need to do anyway), and could write out to each account file as you detect which account # the data is for. If the file is not sorted by account #, you could keep up to a certain number of file output streams open at once, closing them only when you reach the end of the file, or when there are too many open. If you need to further append to a file for an account #, just re-open in append mode. The input file could be any size, with time taken to process it will be directly proportional to its size.

Regular expressions are for finding definable patterns in data, not for spotting unique values.